# while installing yii2/jui package getting error

Tags: xampp, yii2, crud

> Using version ~2.0@dev for yiisoft/yii2-jui ./composer.json has been
>   updated Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/jquery/jquery, enter your
>   GitHub credentials to go over the API rate limit A token will be
>   created and stored in
>   "C:/Users/nimmy/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json", your password
>   will never be stored To revoke access to this token you can visit
>   https://github.com/settings/applications Username:

I am getting above error while I try to install yii2/jui. I want do use a datepicker. I tried to install datepicker and composer also, but I am getting the same error.

What could I try next?

Comment: Did you enter your username and password?

Comment: I have entered a username and password. but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You should try `composer self-update`. Then run `update` again. Keep in mind, that GitHub imposes a limit of 60 requests per hour for unauthorized user's IP!

By entering your credentials, or alternatively it may ask you for your Authorization Token (which you can generate inside GitHub and provide to composer when prompted for it), you should extend your limit to 5000 requests per hour.

If everything is done correctly, but composer keeps saying that the Authentication Token is wrong, try making a new GitHub account and try updating again providing the credentials for the new account. In the past I had a problem when an account had the wrong authorized requests counter stored by GitHub which was counting all requests as unauthorized, making new account worked like a charm, although figuring out the problem and reporting it worked also ;)